# Training in batches but testing individual data item in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have trained a convolution neural network with batch size of 10.
However when testing, I want to predict the classification for each dataset separately and not in batches, this gives error:

```
Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,3] rhs shape= [10,3]
```

I understand 10 refers to `batch_size` and 3 is the number of classes that I am classifying into.

Can we not train using batches and test individually?

**Update:**

Training Phase:

```
batch_size=10
classes=3
#vlimit is some constant : same for training and testing phase
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size,vlimit ], name='X_placeholder')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, classes], name='Y_placeholder')
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[vlimit, classes], stddev=0.01), name='weights')
b = tf.Variable(tf.ones([batch_size,classes]), name="bias")
logits = tf.matmul(X, w) + b
entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y, name='loss')
loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

Testing Phase:

```
batch_size=1
classes=3
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size,vlimit ], name='X_placeholder')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, classes], name='Y_placeholder')
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[vlimit, classes], stddev=0.01), name='weights')
b = tf.Variable(tf.ones([batch_size,classes]), name="bias")
logits = tf.matmul(X, w) + b
entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y, name='loss')
loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

Comment: I believe this should be possible. Can you add example code to show what placeholders (lhs, rhs) or variables etc. you have defined?

Comment: updated the question!!!

Comment: Are both phases part of the same Tensorflow graph?

Comment: i save the network, and then restore it during testing phase in a separate file.

Comment: Before I answer, is there a reason that `batch_size` is used for `b`? Do you not want the same number of biases as weights in your model? That's the standard for a fully connected model...

Comment: i want a bias for each class, i think i wrote the code incorrectly, modifying it now though

Comment: As @Engineero mentioned, try using `vlimit` instead of `batch_size` for `b`.

One final code point - use `logits = tf.add( tf.matmul(X, w) , b)` instead. `+` is a base python operator and will be slower!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define your placeholder, use:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, vlimit ], name='X_placeholder')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, classes], name='Y_placeholder')
...
```

instead for both your training and testing phase (actually, you shouldn't need to re-define these for the testing phase). Also define your bias as:

```
b = tf.Variable(tf.ones([classes]), name="bias")
```

Otherwise you are training a separate bias for each sample in your batch, which is not what you want.

TensorFlow should automatically unroll along the first dimension of your input and recognize that as the batch size, so for training you can feed it batches of 10, and for testing you can feed it individual samples (or batches of 100 or whatever).

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. Placeholders are 'buckets' that get fed data from your inputs. The only thing they do is direct data into your model. They can act like 'infinite buckets' using the `None` trick - you can chuck as much (or as little) data into them as you want (depending on available resources obviously).

In training, try replacing `batch_size` with `None` for the Training placeholders:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, vlimit ], name='X_placeholder')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, classes], name='Y_placeholder')
```

Then define everything else you have as before.

Then do some training ops, for example:

```
 _, Tr_loss, Tr_acc = sess.run([optimizer, loss, accuracy], feed_dict{x: btc_x, y: btc_y})
```

For testing, re-use these same placeholders (`X`,`Y`) and don't bother redefining the other variables.

All Tensorflow variables are static for a single Tensorflow graph definition. If you're restoring the model, then the placeholders still exist from when it was trained. As will the other variables e.g. `w`,`b`,`logits`,`entropy` & `optimizer`.

Then do some testing op, for example:

```
 Ts_loss, Ts_acc = sess.run( [loss, accuracy], feed_dict{ x: test_x , y: test_y } )
```